# Unity:Time.timescale =0 not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to display player tutorial when the user 1st starts the game using playerpref and want the game to be paused, the problem i am facing is that Time.timescale=0 is not pausing the game when placed inside start (tutorialCanvas gets displayed), but works when is called by a button(Pause button).

Following is the code I use

```
void Start()
{ 
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("test4") ==false ) {
        tutorialCanvas.SetActive (true);
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other code somewhere in Start that set the Time.timescale to something else? You have to be careful.

Comment: You did not place it inside the `Start` function. You placed it inside `if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("test4") ==false )` which is in the `Start` function so you must make sure that `if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("test4") ==false )` condition is met. Put `Debug.Log` inside that and see if it shows anything in the Console tab.

Comment: Are you certain the game is not paused? It is a common expectation that `Update` will stop getting called when timeScale is 0, but that is not the case.

Comment: already used Debug.Log inside it. The log is shown in the console !!!. @Programmer

Comment: Ok. Now, put ` Debug.Log(Time.timeScale)` inside the `Update` function to see if it still says `0` after you set it to 0 in the `Start` function. Let me know the outcome. FYI, If it doesn't say `0`, you are also changing it from somewhere else in your code and you need to search your whole script, find where that place is and comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

`Time.timeScale = 0` is really messed up for me so what i could recommend you is that if you just want to pause something like pausing a movement of a character then you can try it like this :

```
GameObject PlayerScript;
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P)){
    //lets disable the playermovement script only not the whole object
    PlayerScript = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().enabled = false;
}
```

I've been stucked there also so i made an alternative way. And you can also visit this [one](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/31225). If you want a free of that asset you can get it [here](http://diskokosmiko.mx/ZEROGIGA/unity-5-13468/chronos-time-control-v2-2,54513.unitypackage)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently, although it was only doing it on a build, and not in the editor. Changing timeScale to something like 0.0001f would fix it, but that wasn't a great solution. Creating an input settings asset (under Camera -> Player Input -> Open Input Settings) seemed to have fixed it for the builds.